# Button in excel not being clicked

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2016, vba

[image]

When I click on 'Calendar' or 'Generate Report' button. It doesn't do anything. what could be the problem. Please help me out. thank you.

Comment: Can you give more details? Like perhaps the code behind the buttons actions?

Comment: Sub Macro1()

    Range("M23").Select
    Application.CommandBars("Stop Recording").Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Calendar1").Select
End Sub

Comment: This code just set the macro recording toolbar to not be seen. Is it what you want it to do? And did you set Macro1 to the action of the button? ie private sub commandbutton1_click() Macro1 end sub?

Answer (score 1):

Either no macro is being assigned to your buttons or you are in design mode.

1. Right click on button and click on Assign Macro's and check if any macro is assigned
2. Go to Developer tab and check if you are in Design Mode

Comment: Macro is there. and it's not in Design Mode.
I am unable to change date and click button.

Comment: is the file macro enabled file ?

Comment: Macro might not be functional. You need to provide more details, cant solve just by looking at screenshot

Comment: I can share the file. please provide your email address.

Comment: not sure if we can share email id's. Cant you attach your file somewhere on StackOverflow or some other website? I will download it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... Assuming you've enabled macros on your workbook correctly etc...

1. The Button.

There are 2 types of button. A form and a Active-x.
If this is a Forms type button - right click and assign the macro. Have your macro in a modules and not in a worksheet class.

1. The Button.
   If this is an active-x button, on the Developer tab press the Design Mode icon, which funny enough, will put it in Design Mode :)
   Double click the button, this will generate an event handler in the worksheet class.

   2. The Calendar Control.
      This is also an active-x so I would follow the steps for the active-x button. Enter design mode and double click. I think this will create a Click event handler where you can trap the event.

Hope that helps...